# Apply multiple functions to list elements based on their name in R

Tags: r, list, purrr

Consider the following list structure:

```
AA <- data.frame("variable1" = c("a", "b"), "variable2" = 1:2)
BB <- data.frame("variable1" = c("a", "b"), "variable2" = 3:4)
my_list <- list(AA=AA, BB=BB)

> my_list
$AA
  variable1 variable2
1         a         1
2         b         2

$BB
  variable1 variable2
1         a         3
2         b         4
```

Even though the individual list-elements in `my_list` have the same `variable1` names `a` and `b`, those must be treated as unique to each list-element (as the real data has similarly duplicated variable names and values). Thus, I have two functions designed to manipulate each specific list-element:

```
AA_recoding <- function(x) {
  x$variable1 <- x$variable1 %>%
    recode("a" = "hello")
  return(x)
}

BB_recoding <- function(x) {
  x$variable1 <- x$variable1 %>%
    recode("a" = "goodbye")
  return(x)
}
```

My objective is to apply the `AA_recoding` function to the `AA` list-element, and the `BB_recoding` function to `BB`, to achieve an output like so:

```
$AA
  variable1 variable2
1     hello         1
2         b         2

$BB
  variable1 variable2
1   goodbye         3
2         b         4
```

This seems like a job for a `purrr` functions like `map`/`imap`, but I can't see a way to specifically orient my functions to their respective list-elements by name. My attempts using `glue` (and `paste0`) encounter the following errors:

```
> my_list %>% imap(~.x %>% glue("{.y}_recoding"))
Error: All unnamed arguments must be length 1

> my_list %>% map(~.x %>% paste0(.y,"_recoding"))
Error in paste0(., .y, "_recoding") : 
  the ... list contains fewer than 2 elements
```

Am I fundamentally approaching this problem in the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `map2` that applies corresponding functions to elements of the `list` by wrapping the functions in a `list`

```
library(purrr)
map2(my_list, list(AA_recoding, BB_recoding), ~ .y(.x))
#$AA
#  variable1 variable2
#1     hello         1
#2         b         2

#$BB
#  variable1 variable2
#1   goodbye         3
#2         b         4
```

Note that the above `list` (`list(AA_recoding, BB_recoding)`) was created manually in the same order of names as in 'my_list', but it can be automated as well with `paste/str_c` and `mget` (to return the value)

```
library(stringr)
map2(my_list, mget(str_c(names(my_list), '_recoding')), ~ .y(.x))
```

---

Or if we want to get the function value from the `names` of the `list` from `imap`, either get the value by wrapping with `match.fun`

```
my_list %>% 
     imap(~ match.fun(str_c(.y, '_recoding'))(.x))
```

or use `get`

```
my_list %>% 
     imap(~ get(str_c(.y, '_recoding'))(.x))
```

Comment: *facepalm*... Thanks @akrun. If you don't mind, can you please explain how `map2` knows the corresponding function without an `AA`/`BB` index? Is it an ordinal progression down the lists?

Comment: @Scott The `list` I created `list(AA_recoding, BB_recoding)` is in the same order of names of `my_list`.  if you want to automate, you can try `map2(my_list, mget(str_c(names(my_list), '_recoding')), ~ .y(.x))`

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly the clarification I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many conditions you have, you could combine your function into a single recoding function and then use `lapply` to apply it conditionally based on the names of the items in the list.

This is a bit hacky, since lapply doesn't retain the names of individual lists. So, create a column in each data frame that corresponds to the name of the list, and then apply your new combined function using `lapply`.

```
new_list <- my_list
list_names <- c("AA", "BB")
for(i in 1:length(my_list)){
  new_list[[i]]$name <- list_names[[i]]
}

> new_list # Looks like this
$AA
  variable1 variable2 name
1         a         1   AA
2         b         2   AA

$BB
  variable1 variable2 name
1         a         3   BB
2         b         4   BB

# Combined function
AA_BB_recoding <- function(x){
  x$variable1 <- ifelse(x$name == "AA", x$variable1 %>%
    recode("a" = "hello"), x$variable1 %>%
      recode("a" = "goodbye"))
  return(x)
}

> lapply(new_list, function(f) AA_BB_recoding(f))

# returns
$AA
  variable1 variable2 name
1     hello         1   AA
2         b         2   AA

$BB
  variable1 variable2 name
1   goodbye         3   BB
2         b         4   BB
```